# Add a user comment in a crystal report at run time

Tags: crystal-reports

Our ERP system uses Crystal Reports to generate Company Stationary, which is used with an automail process to send out via email

In this case a user has ask if they could, at run time, type in a message on a Customer Statement, for example "Hi here is your statement please see invoice 00022 this is the one with the query". Clearly this message may not always be required and would be different at each run.

The only method to do this I have found is to use a txt parameter, but the problem is the input box at run time does not explain with the text typed, so if you make a typo you can not see it.

Can this be done with a pop up box in code?
I have looked for examples but not found anything

Comment: I've implemented this with an application that built parameters for the report. The web based application generated forms to fill out report parameters to pass to the Asp.net hosted Crystal report viewer. It wasn't a Crystal feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something that Crystal itself supports. It's read-only: Once a report is loaded, it's done calculating. If you refresh it, it performs the same calculations.

Like you said, you could use a text parameter where the user could enter a single clump of notes. In theory you could even include a parameter where you enter the invoice numbers that you want the message to appear next to. But that opens the whole can of worms regarding "How do I error check this?" and "What if the invoice number is in the wrong place?"

In short this isn't something you'd want to attempt in Crystal. If this report is launched by an app *you* developed, I'd try to make it a feature in the app. But reports are effectively read-only, and short of writing your own SQL commands, you'll have a bad time trying to write with a read-only system.